# Instruction format of li (load immediate) in MIPS 32-bit?

Tags: mips, mips32

I am working with MIPS 32-bit and just curious about the maximum bits of the immediate value in the `li` instruction. I have made a search on the internet with results that are not consistent, some of them said that the maximum bits of the immediate field could be **16**, **32** or **both**. From my understanding, the `li` instruction is following the I-instruction format and therefore, in MIPS 32-bit, the immediate value should only have 16 bits. Could someone please tell me if this way of thinking wrong and help me clarify it?

Comment: You are correct. An I-Type instruction has a 16-bit immediate.  To get more you would need multiple instructions.

Comment: Hi, so in MIPS 32-bit, the `li` instruction is following the I-format right?

Comment: Yes: `li` is a pseudo instruction that the assembler will convert to `addi $target, $0, value`, which is an I-Type (or something else equivalent, any other I-Type, like `ori`).

Answer (score 0):

`li` is a pseudo-instruction supported by MIPS-32 assemblers, not a "real" instruction.  So the assembler actually generates *two* instructions for the `li` "instruction" -- an `lui` instruction to set the upper 16 bits of the destination, followed by an `ori` instruction to set the lower 16 bits.

The fact that it is a pseudo-instruction is important if you try to put it in a branch delay slot -- it won't actually work properly; you'll only get the `lui` half if the branch is taken.  Most assemblers will give you a warning about this.